# Краш при старте приложения

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, делаю приложение для html парсинга странички, но при старте вылетает сообщение ошибки. Как поправить?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 
java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
at com.ekchang.jsouper.sample.MoviesAdapter.loadData(MoviesAdapter.java:47)
```

**MoviesAdapter.java**

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends
RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Movie> items = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
return new ViewHolder(
    (ItemMoviesBinding) 
DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
        viewType, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
Movie movie = items.get(position);
Picasso.with(holder.binding.getRoot().getContext())
    .load(movie.cover.imageUrl)
    .into(holder.binding.cover);

holder.binding.title.setText(movie.detail.title);
holder.binding.price.setText(movie.rating.price);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
return R.layout.item_movies;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return items.size();
}

public void loadData(List<Movie> movies) {
items.clear();
items.addAll(movies);
notifyItemRangeInserted(0, movies.size());
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 public final ItemMoviesBinding binding;

public ViewHolder(ItemMoviesBinding binding) {
  super(binding.getRoot());
  this.binding = binding;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Без кода сказать нечего, кроме как ваша коллекция(`ArrayList`) вызывает `NullPointerException`, то ли вы делаете `toArray()` где то, то ли `addAll()`.

Comment: Без кода Вам просто дадут ссылку как лечить NPE. Добавьте код и есть шанс, что добрые дяди тети найдут ошибку

Comment: items.addAll(movies); Такое есть

Comment: Проверьте, в метод loadData movies не null?